# Jetty Websockets - How should sendPing and sendPong be used?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I'm using jetty (9.2.7 and 9.3.5) websockets to send a large number of (small) messages to connected clients and I'm having trouble when trying detect failed (disconnected) connections and thus, when trying to reconnect on client side (browser JS).

As I understand, the ping/pong mechanism is used automatically by the websocket implementation to detect if the connection is active, but I've seen some issues when the the connection is terminated "abnormally", for example, when a user closes the laptop (enters standby) and then re-opens it after a few hours.

In this case, the server won't receive the close event until a very long time passes (1 or 1.5 hours sometimes), and also, on client side, the onClose event can take a few minutes until is triggered or the connection is automatically established (which can happen in a few seconds after the user connects to the internet or sometimes a few minutes).

In case of Jetty, I've seen that the RemoteEndpoint class has 2 methods sendPing and sendPong, but I don't know exactly how should I use them.

For example, since [sendPing](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.6.v20151106/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/RemoteEndpoint.html#sendPing-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) will expect a reply, and also throws an IOException, I'm assuming that if I use it once per minute (with a limited number of retries let's say), I should detect (on server side) that the client is no longer connected and thus, remove it from list of connections, correct?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am using the same component, and I've had the same trouble with mobile endpoints, and trying to solve this with sendPing, i found that for instance SocketRocket v0.5.1 does not respond to sendPing on the didReceivePingWithData delegate.

Comment: Hi, I didn't found a way to use sendPing as I initially wanted, but I created a custom mechanism, where the client pings the server and checks a response, and also the server executes a traversal through all connected clients to see if they sent a ping. This is done periodically at a time chosen based on your custom app logic.